\CMake was unexpected at this time
I'm trying to build Blender, and I had ued the CMake thing in Visual Studio, or at least I activated it, and then I got this error after running Make. Here's the code so far:
D:\Goo-Engine\blender>make
No explicit msvc version requested, autodetecting version.
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.9.6
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
Compiler Detection successful, detected VS2022
Cmake not found in path, required for building, exiting...

D:\Goo-Engine\blender>make
No explicit msvc version requested, autodetecting version.
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.9.6
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
Compiler Detection successful, detected VS2022
Cmake not found in path, required for building, exiting...

After using CMake in Visual Studio:
D:\Goo-Engine\blender>make
No explicit msvc version requested, autodetecting version.
\CMake was unexpected at this time.

How do I fix this?
Tried to build Blender, expected similar dialogue to:
-- Installing:
C:\blender-git\build_windows_Full_x64_vc14_Release\bin\Release\\somefile\]


“detected VS2022 Cmake not found in path, required for building, exiting...” So, does your installation of VS 2022 have its Cmake installed? Or is the lack of proper formatting in the question causing some confusion?

And why is python tagged?
